# Trouble adding user defined function in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

As a follow up question to [doctrine2 and group_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864345/doctrine2-and-group-concat), I've been trying to add the GroupConcat user defined function from [beberlei](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) to my project, without success. I tried using the [offical procedure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html), but I'm using Doctrine 2 with annotation references so I don't have a config.yaml file. I stumbled into [this procedure](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html), which seems simple enough, but the function is still not recognized when I try to use it in a DQL query. Here's the error :

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 49: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got 'GroupConcat' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MTG\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php on line 44
```

**UPDATE :**

I realise that the procedure can be very different from one setup to another. In my case, since I first installed Doctrine using [the tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html), I have to put that stuff in my     `bootstrap.php` file. Here's what I did so far:

1) Install DoctrineExtensions using composer.

2) Add the following to my bootstrap.php file to load the classes :

```
Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', realpath(__DIR__.'/vendor/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/lib'));
$classLoader->register();
```

3) Change my bootstrap.php file to define the function :

```
$config->addCustomStringFunction('GroupConcat', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\GroupConcat');
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I'm trying to find out if the class actually loads.

Comment: Why do you manually manager your vendor folder and not let composer do it?

Comment: I didn't use composer since I first installed it along with Doctrine and I forgot it's existence. I deleted the whole thing and started over with doctrine + extensions over composer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that after modifying correctly my `bootstrap.php` file, I was still unable to make the function work. After some fiddling, I found out that while my query still doesn't work, the function *do* work using this form :

```
$results = $s->select("GroupConcat(t.name) As Name")->from("Type","t")->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So, after all, my problem resides in the DQL syntax using GroupConcat.